# List all available font awesome icons for Leaflet map in Shiny, R

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, font-awesome

I'm makin a Shiny App where I want the user to be able choose the Font Awesome icon that goes into an Awesome Marker.

Here's a simple app that lets the user choose the marker colour, the icon colour and the icon (name).

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

icon_names <- c("home", "map-pin")

marker_colours <- list(Standard = c('red', 'orange', 'beige', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 
                                    'pink', 'cadetblue', 'white', 'grey', 'black'),
                       Shades   = c('darkred', 'lightred', 'darkgreen', 'lightgreen', 
                                    'darkblue', 'lightblue', 'darkpurple', 'lightgray'))


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({

    icons <- awesomeIcons(
      icon        = input$icon,
      iconColor   = input$icon_colour,
      library     = 'fa',
      markerColor = input$marker_colour
    )

    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      addAwesomeMarkers(lng            = 4.9, 
                        lat            = 52.38,
                        icon           = icons
      )
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("icon", "Icon:", 
                  choices = icon_names, selected = "home"),
      selectInput("marker_colour", "Marker colour:", 
                  choices = marker_colours, selected = "red"),
      selectInput("icon_colour", "Icon colour:", 
                  choices = c("#ffffff", "#000000"), selected = "#ffffff")
    ),
    mainPanel(leafletOutput("map"))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But now I want a way to access all the possible FA icons available in the R package Leaflet.

So the bit of code

```
icon_names <- c("home", "map-pin")
```

should change to something that would result in a string with all available icons.

Your advice is much appreciated!

Best,
Jiddu

Answer (score 9):

I've found a way to gather the info from the leaflet package.

You should be able to find a file in the leaflet package called font-awesome.min.css, and you can extract the info there.

```
file_text <- readr::read_file(
  paste0(.libPaths()[1], 
  "/leaflet/htmlwidgets/plugins/Leaflet.awesome-markers/font-awesome.min.css")
)
```

The icon names are gathered between 'fa-' and ':'.

```
icon_names <- stringr::str_extract_all(file_text, "(fa-)([^:]+)")[[1]]
```

A quick glance shows that the first 36 entries are not what I want, as you can see by viewing the the whole css file.

```
icon_names <- icon_names[-(1:36)] %>% 
  stringr::str_sub(4, -1)
```

I assume that changes in the Leaflet package can affect this. For me it works with:

- leaflet_1.1.0
- stringr_1.2.0
- readr_1.0.0
- R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)

Best,
Jiddu